# How to Get a Css-Only Lightbox to Function with Multiple Images on a Single Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, lightbox

Can I apply a CSS-only lightbox feature to an array of different images on a single page?

I've provided an example which displays 3 different images, with the lightbox function applied; however, all images only seem to grab the first image listed, once the lightbox is prompted.

See the snippet below for reference:

```js
$('.pic > img').each(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $(this).closest('.container').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);

});
```

```css
.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox:target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox:target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox:target ~ #customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox:target ~ #customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox:target ~ #customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
    <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
      <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
    <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
    <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
      <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
    <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
    </div>
  </a>
  <div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
    <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
      <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img">
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
    <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Any help, or input, would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create only one div for lightbox and replace the source of image depending upon the click of image

```js
$('.pic > img').click(function() {
  var srcToCopy = $(this).attr('src');
  $('body').find('.imgsrc').attr('src', srcToCopy);
});
```

```css
.pic,
#imgsrc {
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  width: 100px
}

a {
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 0;
}

.container {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  line-height: 0;
}

.customlightbox {
  top: 0%;
  bottom: 0%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
  z-index: -5;
  opacity: 0;
}

.customlightbox-imgwrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 20px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
}

.customlightbox img {
  width: auto;
  margin: auto;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

#customlightbox-controls {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: fixed;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  top: -50px;
  right: -3px;
  z-index: 5;
  border-left: 2px solid white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid white;
  opacity: .7;
}

#close-customlightbox {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 30px;
  width: 30px;
  right: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
}

#close-customlightbox:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  height: 0px;
  width: 2px;
  left: 14px;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

#close-customlightbox:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  width: 0px;
  height: 2px;
  top: 14px;
  left: 0;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.customlightbox:target {
  z-index: 4;
  opacity: 1;
  display: inline-block;
}

.customlightbox:target img {
  opacity: 1;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls {
  top: -3px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:after {
  width: 30px;
}

.customlightbox:target~#customlightbox-controls #close-customlightbox:before {
  height: 30px;
}

.lb-animate {
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -ms-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  -o-transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
  transition: 0.5s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Lightbox Instance 1 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://syedimranrocks.files.wordpress.com/2012/09/flower01low1.png">
    </div>
  </a>

</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 2 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="http://downloadicons.net/sites/default/files/Rose-Coral-Icon-906534.png">
    </div>
  </a>

</div>

<!-- Lightbox Instance 3 -->
<div class="container">
  <a href="#view">
    <div class="pic">
      <img src="https://images.vexels.com/media/users/3/136645/isolated/lists/54b1517db1906889a6971939de45d2a8-purple-sunflower-cartoon.png">
    </div>
  </a>

</div>
<!--lightbox-->
<div class="customlightbox lb-animate" id="view">
  <div class="customlightbox-imgwrap">
    <img class="imgsrc" id="customlightbox-img" src="">
  </div>
</div>
<div id="customlightbox-controls" class="lb-animate">
  <a id="close-customlightbox" class="lb-animate" href="#!"></a>
</div>
```

Comment: Lovely answer the way to go.

Comment: Works perfect now. Thanks!